# How to split a string based on certain regex? (In python)

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that is a bunch of sentences that are split up by things like "title": , "date": , etc.

I want to split up this string based on those delimiters. Right now I have this ..

```
line =  re.split(r'("[a-z]: ")', line)



  {"date": "Jul 18, 2017, 4:10 AM", 
    "text": "Best / cheapest", 
    "state_or_country_or_utility": "Norway Travel Forum", 
    "responses": ["The local train www.nsb.no"],
    "title": "airport transfer "}
```

Comment: It sounds like it might be JSON, you can use `json.loads()` to parse it.

Comment: I did use that, but I was getting a bunch of valueerrors for some reason. I think this could be easier

Comment: Show a complete sample of the input.

Comment: {"date": "Jul 18, 2017, 4:10 AM", "text": "Best / cheapest", "state_or_country_or_utility": "Norway Travel Forum", "responses": ["The local train www.nsb.no"], "title": "airport transfer "}

Comment: Put it in the question so you can show it with proper formatting.

Comment: And that really does look like JSON. Post the code that got the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
s = '{"date": "Jul 18, 2017, 4:10 AM", "text": "Best / cheapest", "state_or_country_or_utility": "Norway Travel Forum", "responses": ["The local train www.nsb.no"], "title": "airport transfer "}'
final_data = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

Output:

```
{'date': 'Jul 18, 2017, 4:10 AM', 'text': 'Best / cheapest', 'state_or_country_or_utility': 'Norway Travel Forum', 'responses': ['The local train www.nsb.no'], 'title': 'airport transfer '}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is JSON, you can use `json.loads()`.

import json

```
data = '''{"date": "Jul 18, 2017, 4:10 AM", 
    "text": "Best / cheapest", 
    "state_or_country_or_utility": "Norway Travel Forum", 
    "responses": ["The local train www.nsb.no"],
    "title": "airport transfer "}'''

result = json.loads(data)
print('Title = ', result['title'])
print('Date = ', result['date'])
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/8T3bFt)